# MTOM Java WebServices authentication

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, mtom

Im looking for a simple and secure way to authenticate users throug axis2/mtom webservice...

Something like http authentication... or session cookie auth.

A live example will help me a lot.

I have this webservice that receive an image and process it... i will need to ask for an authentication and a way to process that user with the image (example, move the image to the user's folder)...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the easiest way is to do it at the deployment level. e.g. [For Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html)